# Is there a way in python to use one column as index to change element of other string column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with two columns that look something like this:

```
      A           B
0  '_______'    [2,3]
1  '_______'    [0]
2  '_______'    [1,4,6]
```

where one column is a string with 7 "_" and the other column contains a numpy array with different lengths. My goal is to change column A using B as indexes so it looks like this:

```
             A           B     
    1   '__23___'   [2,3]    
    2   '0______'    [0]      
    3   '_1__4_6'   [1,4,6]
```

My code seems to work but I keep getting the error:

> SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

I don't understand how I fix this error. My code is:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    row = df.iloc[i,:].copy()
    numbers = row['B']
    for j in numbers:
       loop_string = df['A'][i]
       df['A'][i] = loop_string[:j] + str(j) + loop_string[j+1:]
```

Also the fact that I need two for loops bothers me this must be possible an other more efficient way. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to use a custom function on the `B` column:

```
df['A'] = df['B'].apply(lambda l: ''.join([str(i) if i in l else '_'for i in range(7)]))
```

The above does not consider the original value of `A` but instead creates an entirely new string column.

Result:

```
          A          B
0   __23___     [2, 3]
1   0______        [0]
2   _1__4_6  [1, 4, 6]
```